# How should my app handle the current date if it uses it throughout its runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Where should I put a Date instance and how should I handle calling it in order to get the current date? Should I make a singleton with a date instance? Should I call this instance in one of AppDelegate's functions in order to update the current date when the app isn't on use?

Comment: What's the purpose for keeping the date instance?  For recording some kind of the last action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts of your question don't really make sense:

"Where should I put a Date instance and how should I handle calling it in order to get the current date?"

A Date instance records a fixed moment in time. The code

```
let date = Date()
```

will record the current date at time at the instant it's called, and not change. If your program is still running tomorrow, that date will now be very "out of date".

Instead you should use the expression `Date()` any time you need the current date.

Comment: I did not know you could use Date() like that. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Where should I put a Date instance and how should I handle calling it in order to get the current date? "
In your current View Controller is good enough. As long as the VC is alive, it 
has a strong reference to your Date object.

"Should I make a singleton with a date instance?"
No. If you need to keep date relevant you need to fire a timer (let's say 1 minute
so it won't bother much) that will keep the date updated in UI

"Should I call this instance in one of AppDelegate's functions in order to update the current date when the app isn't on use?"
No, you can get notifications and by them know when to put timer up or down.
See code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
// label to hold the date
@IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!

// timer to keep it updated
var fetchTimer: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set date immediately (dont wait for timer)
    viewDidEnterForeground()

    // follow Foreground so when we re-enter, timer will launch again
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(ViewController.viewDidEnterForeground),
                                           name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
                                           object: nil)

    // follow background for invalidating timer
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(ViewController.viewDidEnterBackground),
                                           name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground,
                                           object: nil)
}
// on each entry - set date and fire timer
func viewDidEnterForeground()
{
    setDate()

    fetchTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0,
                                      target: self,
                                      selector: #selector(timerFunc),
                                      userInfo: nil,
                                      repeats: true)
}
func viewDidEnterBackground()
{
    fetchTimer.invalidate()
}
func timerFunc()
{
    setDate()
}
func setDate()
{
    let date = Date()

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

    // "22.04.2017"
    let dateFormatString = formatter.string(from: date)

    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.dateLabel.text = dateFormatString
    }
}
deinit
{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}
}
```